# ng-grid filter cell template column

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I created a grid with column defs and showFilter. One column use cellTemplate to manipulate the output, based on value of that field.

When I try filter data, I notice that filter ignores that column.

How I filter all columns from grid, including the column that refers cellTemplate?

This is my grid:

```
$scope.gridStatusOptions = {
            data: 'status',
            showFilter: true,
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', cellFilter: '', cellTemplate: '' },
                        { field: 'value', displayName: 'Value', cellFilter: '', cellTemplate: "<div class='ngCellText' ng-class='col.colIndex()'><span>{{formatState(row.entity)}}</span></div>"}]
};
```

Regards

Comment: Show us some of your code please. Especially the cellTemplate. And, since you are new here, take the TOUR in the HELP dropdown at the top of this page to find out how to properly as questions.

Comment: I added my grid to my question. Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Filters in `ng-grid` work on the underlying data and not what is rendered to the `DOM` of your browser.

This has to be so, because if your data is coming from the server it also has to be prefiltered, paginated and sorted on the server side.

If you don't have the (to be filtered) fields in the right format, do a transform on the data and add preformated fields.

Look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925615/nggrid-cell-value-is-an-enum-value-how-do-i-use-the-enum-name/25934387#25934387) that I gave just a few days ago.

Btw: If you want to format the code in your question properly just select it and hit `CTRL-K`. Makes it more readable.

Comment: I think you dont understood my question. I want filter (search) my data, i dont want sorter or something else. I just want use showfilter to view only specific values.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your Question. Maybe you create a Plunker or a fiddle to show what's the issue. Clarify if you use server-sided data or client sided. My linked answer is all about filtering in ng-grid.

Comment: Here is the plunkler: http://plnkr.co/edit/jMvafIjqCsU0cnW6Ecvy?p=preview. My problem is when we use cellTemplate grid propertie, the filter do not work properly. To simulate this scenario, you can try search by person2@gmail.com that you'll notice the problem. In this plunker, I use a cellTemplate to concatenate '@gmail.com' to person's email so if you type person2 the filter is applied, but after type @ you'll see that filter do not work. Can someone help me? Thank you!